# Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported when including child table in query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I've got a simple one-to-many db relationship defined by EF 6.1. The database that is generated appears correct and has the appropriate explicit relationship. However, when I try a query involving the child table, I get a NotSupportedException (see title of post). The failing code is in GetContractList (see below).

I did some digging and found some people having this problem, but those issues seemed related to attempting to include non-entity items in queries; I don't think that's what's happening here.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Table("Contract")]
public class Contract : IContract
{
    [Key,
        DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1023),
        Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBegin { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IMarket> Markets { get; set; }

    public Contract()
    {
        Markets = new List<IMarket>();
}    
}    

[Table("Market")]
public class Market : IMarket
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ContractId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int MarketId { get; set; }
}


public IEnumerable<IIdName> GetContractList(IAffiliateContractSearchCriteria criteria)
{
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

// This is the line throwing the exception.
return _repository.AsQueryable().Where(c => (criteria.IncludeOnlyActive
    ? c.DateBegin < now
    && (c.DateEnd > now || c.DateEnd <= SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
    : true)
    && (c.Markets.Any()
    ? c.Markets.Select(m => m.MarketId).Any(x => criteria.MarketIds.Contains(x))
    : true)).OrderBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => new IdName() { Id = a.AffiliateContractId, Name = a.Name });
}

public class ContractSearchCriteria : IContractSearchCriteria
{
    public bool IncludeOnlyActive { get; set; }
    public List<int> MarketIds { get; set; }

    public ContractSearchCriteria()
    {
        IncludeOnlyActive = false;
        MarketIds = new List<int>();
    }

    public ContractSearchCriteria(bool includeOnlyActive, int[] marketIds)
        : this()
    {
        IncludeOnlyActive = includeOnlyActive;
        MarketIds.AddRange(marketIds);
    }
```

}

Comment: Just so you know: `"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."` (from [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). Generally we don't like to see "Why isn't my code working" questions on SO. Your question might be better received on [/* Programmers /*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The specific error is in the title of the post, as I stated in the post. I should be able to include child tables in my queries, and not receive a NotSupportedException.

Comment: As it stands, your question is a good one, and is welcome here. I just wanted to give you a heads up since you appear to be new to stack. Welcome!

Comment: Hint: try and error, remove all conditions, start put it one by one, like only `c.DateBegin < now && (c.DateEnd > now || c.DateEnd <= SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)`, and then `criteria.IncludeOnlyActive ? PreviousCondition : true`, until you find which part that causes the error, or perhaps start from the `Select` clause, to take full properties, `Select(x => x)`

Comment: It doesn't like Markets at all . . . . I think I'm realizing that EF doesn't support interfaces in the way I'm using them . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that you can't use interfaces when defining EF Entity objects and relationships.

My bad.